# Automatic Annotation of Videos/Images

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, annotation

I have joined a group working on building models for sperm morphology analysis. There are doctors annotating sperm data. Now that we have several models, we want an application that automatically annotates the videos/images with the models first, and then doctors will make corrections. What is the best solution available? Are there such a capable apps or we should build it?